# Value of $D_{x}y$ in exponential function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> If $y=e^{x^2-3x}$. Then value of $D_{x}y$ is

What i try::

$$D_{x}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=e^{x^2-3x}\cdot (2x-3)$$

$$D_{x}y=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\bigg)=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\bigg(e^{x^2-3x}\cdot (2x-3)\bigg)=0$$

Is my solution is right. If not , Then How do i solve it . Help me please. Thanks

Comment: What the hell is $D_x$ ?

Comment: Actually i did not understand the meaning of  $D_{x}y$. I though it is partial derivatives

Comment: where did you get it from, post an image or sth, please